# How can I fix the Skyrim Forever Mourning Bug if I have already returned to Jorrvaskr with the witches' heads?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have already returned to Vilkas after killing the witches; it then went into forever mourning mode. I did not realise this was a glitch at first, and now have far too much play time after to throw away in order to go back to before the bug. I have tried running through the silver hand place and got the helm of Winterhold (without killing anyone), which I then returned, however the bug remains. Is there any way around it?

Comment: Experienced the same problem,  the latest patch on consoles fixes this glitch.

Answer (score 0):

For PC version, first go find Vilkas, then open the console and type `setstage c05 10`. This will cause any follower to leave you and Vilkas to join you and starts the quest.

For Xbox and PS3 possible fix and more info, read **Bugs** section in [this page](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Purity_of_Revenge).